# Update array in rails action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in an action:

```
@user = @current_user
@user.votes[1430]='up'
@user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

Votes is a string type, there is no default value - I just want to set it for the first time when this action occurs.

Unfortunately I get this error:
NoMethodError

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.votes

any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error seems to be that @user is a nil reference.

You can confirm this by using logging and checking in your console window:

logger.info "user is nil" if @user.nil?

You are assigning @user to be the value of @current_user. I've seen this pattern before and usually current_user is a function, declared elsewhere, not an instance variable. If you are using that pattern, the line should be something like @user = current_user instead.

(Additionally, if votes is a string, your second line appears to be referring to index 1430 of that string, which is probably not what you want either.)

Comment: Hi Evil Trout,

Thanks for the answer! Doesn't the index 1430 make votes array? Because if so, its what I'm trying to do.

Got  a similar error from @user = current_user, I'm using authlogic if that makes a difference

Comment: Are you requiring that the user be logged in before this action? And also, the index on votes, if it is a string, will not make it an array, it will look up the character at position 1430 of your string. Here's some more info on that http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000771

Comment: ahh, so how do I make it an array? should it be type text?

Comment: What is the 1430 for? Do you actually want to store an array in your database or just the text 'up'?

Comment: the 1430 is actually two seperate IDs, so the user can vote up, on those items, in their array of votes.

so unless its a huge mistake which I dont understand - I was planning on an array in the db?

Answer (score 0):

I'm splitting off the comments as I don't want to hijack Evil Trouts response and we seem to be veering away from what was initially spoken about.

> Unfortunately I get this error: NoMethodError
>
> You have a nil object when you didn't expect it! The error occurred while evaluating nil.votes

For this, have a look at the [authlogic example](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example/tree/master) application. My guess is that you don't have the appropriate `before_filter` set up and aren't requiring the user to be logged in on that action.

> the 1430 is actually two seperate IDs

I don't fully follow this. It's a concatenation of two IDs? What are the IDs for? To be honest, I've never used an array as being a field type in my database so I don't know what the advantages of it are, but whenever I think to myself that an array would be a good idea, I usually question whether or not it wouldn't be better to just have it be a separate model, and hence, table.

It sounds like the situation you are describing might have a `Question` which a `User` can vote up on. If so, I might have a separate `Voteable` model which would join the users with the questions they can vote 'up' on.

Maybe if you provide some more insight into this side of things, I can make a better suggestion. Cheers.